# Show that sequence of composition of function $f(n) = n + \lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor$ contains at least one perfect square.

Tags: number-theory, problem-solving, ceiling-and-floor-functions

The domain of a function $f$ is the set of natural numbers. The function is defined as
follows:
            $f(n) = n + \lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor$.
Prove that for every natural number $m$ the following sequence contains at
least one perfect square
$m, f(m), f^{2}(m), f^{3}(m),...$

Comment: This is trivial, but if every such sequence contains at least one square then it must contain infinitely many squares, since we can  start the sequence from $f^{(i)}(m)$ for all $i$.