# Step in proof for squares in a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, functions

Can some explain how the highlighted implication is so obvious i cant seem to get there from previous step

[image]

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2288249/prove-that-the-expression-is-a-perfect-square

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of the proof reduces to the case where:
$$
m=k^2+j,
$$
and 
$$
f^2(m)=(k+1)^2+(j-1).
$$

To make sense of the last statement, let's look at a few cases:

- When $j=1$, then $f^2(m)=(k+1)^2$, which is a square.
- When $j=2$, then $f^4(m)=f^2(f^2(m))$.  In this case, $f^2(m)$ is of the same form as $m$ (replacing $k$ by $k+1$ and replacing $j$ by $j-1$).  Therefore, 
  $$
  f^4(m)=f^2((k+1)^2+(j-1))=((k+1)+1)^2+((j-1)-1)=(k+2)^2.
  $$

In general, $f^2(m)$ is of the same form as $m$, but with $j$ smaller by $1$.  By applying $f^2$ $j$ times, each time the extra term (the $j$ term) reduces by $1$ until the remainder is $0$ and we have a square.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH !