# Prove that the sequence contains a perfect square for any natural number $m $ in the domain of $f$ .

Tags: number-theory

> The domain of a function $f$ is the set of natural numbers. The function is defined as follows: $$f(n)=n+\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor$$ where $\lfloor k\rfloor$ denotes the nearest integer smaller than or equal to $k$
>
> Prove that for every natural number $m$ the following sequence contains at least one perfect square $m, f(m), f^2(m),f^3(m),\ldots$.
>
> The notation $f^k$ denotes the function obtained by composing $f$ with itself $k$ times e.g $f^2 = f\circ f.$

I tried this out using induction but I got stuck and couldn't make it. Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Please type out your question, don't post a photo (I've done it for you this time). It means that your question is searchable in the future if it is typed

Comment: Ok I will keep that in mind.. thank you

Comment: This question has appeared several times before on the site.  I think the first answer to [this version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2288249/prove-that-the-expression-is-a-perfect-square) is probably the clearest.